# Responsive Square Parent, with responsive square background image

Tags: css, responsive-design

What I need is simple, but I'm striking out.

I need to create three divs that are a perfect responsive square using vws.
Inside those div's I need div's with a background image that are also perfect squares when you scale your browser.

The catch is that I need the background image to always be a square as well, and resize accordingly so that none of the image is clipped off.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7qd/2/

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</div>

.image-wrapper {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
.image {
    background-image:   url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Square_on_plane.svg/200px-Square_on_plane.svg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 100px;
```

}

Comment: *** if you resize the fiddle to a smaller scale, you can see the image that is not clipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--7gtJQo5mHE/UGMKHZapqmI/AAAAAAAAWGU/5X26Pgj_St4/s1600/funny-cat-pictures-017-005.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="image">
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--7gtJQo5mHE/UGMKHZapqmI/AAAAAAAAWGU/5X26Pgj_St4/s1600/funny-cat-pictures-017-005.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="image">
     <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--7gtJQo5mHE/UGMKHZapqmI/AAAAAAAAWGU/5X26Pgj_St4/s1600/funny-cat-pictures-017-005.jpg"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.image-wrapper {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.image {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 100%;
}

.image img {
width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7qd/12/

Comment: This is changing the markup.  According to the question, he needs the "image" classes to have a bg - not contain an image tag.

Comment: @PhillipKregg what he wants to do can't be done, I've already been there.

Comment: Thanks Carol and Phillip! I was able to change the markup. 

Here's a fiddle of this same issue working with nested DIVs in case some poor soul cannot change their markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/4v3Wx/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for because the only square i see here is the `image-wrapper`. Please check this out.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7qd/6/)

if this is not what you are looking for, can you post some of the images of your desired output.

Comment: Thanks, here's an updated fiddle with a perfect square image.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7qd/2/